# Merging two lists with similar elements in R

Tags: r

I got the two lists:

```
list_1 <- list(a = 1:3, b = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), c = "hello")
list_2 <- list(b = pi, d = "world")
```

I remember there is a function in R to getting the next (merges two lists replacing the repeted objects inside), but I can not remember its name:

```
magicFx(list_1, list_2)

$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 3.141593

$c
[1] "hello"

$d
[1] "world"
```

Comment: a possible way : `list_1[names(list_2)]<-list_2`